# How to hide a discord token on github? discord.py

Tags: python, github, discord.py, token

Discord detect when i have the token in a file on github and reset this. I have tried putting it in an **.env** file and also the default **.gitignore** for python but it doesn't work. I don't understand much of this, any solution?

Comment: You shouldn't commit your token with your code to Github

Comment: It's not for a functional bot, i just test stuff

Comment: make the repo private…?

Comment: If you had already committed a .env file before adding it to the list in .gitignore, then it will still be in the repo and you would need to git rm it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally using. env and I put that in my .gitignore and it works fine for me.
Are you sure you opened the project in the same directory as your .git file?

Besides that you should be able to see what GitHub pushes to GitHub by downloading GitHub Desktop. Which you can download [here](https://desktop.github.com/).

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Create an `.env` file and type in the `.env` file:

```
DISCORD_BOT_SECRET=TOKEN
```